# Do you need UNIQUE for a column declared as PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm following a course which is declaring tables like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

Doesn't `PRIMARY KEY` imply `UNIQUE`?

The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#primkeyconst) says:

> Each row in a table with a primary key must have a unique combination of values in its primary key columns.

and

> A UNIQUE constraint is similar to a PRIMARY KEY constraint, except that a single table may have any number of UNIQUE constraints.

So it looks like you don't need the `UNIQUE` constraint for primary keys?

Comment: Correct, you don't need it.

Comment: It (PRIMARY KEY) also implies NOT NULL, so you don't need that constraint either.

Comment: That may depend on the RDBMS, eg for some you are unable to include a column in a PK definition *unless* it is defined *not null*

Comment: @JonArmstrong in theory yes, but this course is about SQLite, where PRIMARY KEY can be null due to a bug in previous versions and backward compatibility in current versions

Comment: Interesting. That's an odd deviation from the standard.

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, a primary key implies unique key, there is no need to use unique again.

For more kindly read: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key/

From the link we read:

> ### Primary Key
>
> A primary key is a column of a table that uniquely identifies each tuple (row) in that table. The primary key enforces integrity constraints to the table. Only one primary key is allowed to use in a table. The primary key does not accept any duplicate and NULL values. The primary key value in a table changes very rarely so it is chosen with care where the changes can occur in a seldom manner. A primary key of one table can be referenced by the foreign key of another table.

> ### Unique Key
>
> Unique Key constraints also identify an individual tuple uniquely in a relation or table. A table can have more than one unique key, unlike a primary key. Unique key constraints can accept only one NULL value for the column. Unique constraints are also referenced by the foreign key of another table. It can be used when someone wants to enforce unique constraints on a column and a group of columns which is not a primary key.